# Docker overlay network dns alias for unhealty services

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, docker-network

The docker overlay network driver supports an DNS alias `tasks.<service-name>` [from Here](https://docs.docker.com/network/overlay/#container-discovery). However, it only lists tasks that are in the healthy state.

Is there an alias that maps to all tasks independent of their health status?
Only unhealthy ones would also be ok, as well as those of a specific health.